# three.js - Keep object up straight after using lookAt()

Tags: rotation, three.js

I'm trying to figure out how to keep an object (player model) up straight while using a TWEEN to move to a location in combination with lookAt() to face the player model in the direction it's walking to.

```
 this.character.lookAt(new THREE.Vector3(x, y, z));
 new TWEEN.Tween(character.position).to({
   x: x,
   y: y,
   z: z
 }, 1000).start();
```

The issue here is when the Y-position changes (e.g. moving upwards), the player model tilts as well instead of just facing the direction.

Is there a way to force the vertical rotation to stay at 0?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you mean `character.lookAt( new THREE.Vector3( x, character.position.y, z ) );`?

Comment: Sorry, late response. But yeah, that was it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed using:

```
character.lookAt( new THREE.Vector3( x, character.position.y, z ) )
```

Thanks @WestLangley :)